# Change the OpenFlow Configuration on Floodlight

Tags: sdn, pox

I would like to find a way to set the miss_send_len on floodlight to `0xFFFD`

i.e. translate the following POX line

`self.connection.send(of.ofp_set_config(miss_send_len = 0xFFFD))`
into floodlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Modification to 
https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight/blob/master/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/core/internal/OFSwitchHandshakeHandler.java#L1746 was enough to set the miss_send_len to `0xFFFD`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is done during the handshake between the controller and the switches through an OFSetConfig.